# VBA - working with Word selection object

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a below code:

```
Sub testing()

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

objWord.Documents.Add
objWord.Visible = True

Set d = objWord.Documents(1)

objWord.Activate
d.Content.InsertAfter Text:="INSERT TOC HERE"
ActiveDocument.Words(1).Select
st = Selection.Text
```

but after this runs the st variable value is blank ("") - what I am doing wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: Because `Selection` refers to the selection of the application object from which you run the macro, not the one currently holding the document. Use `objWord.Selection` instead. Oh and: if in any way possible do not use selection.

Comment: BTW: Same goes for `ActiveDocument`. I assume this should be `d` instead.

Comment: You're right with both, it helps, thank you